# add character inside string using on keyup regex javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i create function using event on key up to put "/" inside value from input user using regex but still bug, can someone help me ?

```
$('#validUntil').on('keyup', function(e){

                    $(this).val(function(index, value) {
                        return value
                        // Add "/" separators:
                        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, "/")
                    });
});
```

for example if i typing 5121 the result must be 51/21.
the problem is that the results do not match, the displayed results are : 5/1/21

Comment: Can you explain the problem?

Comment: sorry, i updated my problem

Comment: can you type using keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#validUntil').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val.length > 3) {
      $(this).val(val.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, "/"));
    }
    return true;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="validUntil" />
```

I suspect the primary issue is that the value is assessed on each `keyup` event.

Adding a condition to ensure a proper length will help ensure the regex works when it is needed.

Now if the User enters `512111` you will get similar issues. So maybe if `/` is detected, it is remove and then the regex replacement is applied.

Comment: yes bro  thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a slash before the last two numbers in the input, every time its value updates.

So when you are typing:

---

`5`          => `5`

`5` + `1`    => `51`    => `51`

`51` + `2`   => `512`   => `5/12`

`5/12` + `1` => `5/121` => `5/1/21`

---

When inserting the slash, make sure to remove the previously inserted slash:

```js
return value.replaceAll('/', '')
            .replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, "/")
```

Comment: thank you very much bro, replaceAll "/" working well.